# Asp.Net usercontrol codebehind: reference nested class from another usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net

Edit: apparently it was a hickup in VS intellisense. Costed me quite some time, sight. Thanks for the help anyway.

What I'm trying to do is to reference an inner class from one codebehind to the other, I've managed to be able to reference the outer class using `@ reference` and `classname`. However I can't access the inner class. So to be more precise:

```
public partial class A : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public class Inner
    {

    }
}
```

And now in another .ascx(.cs) file:

```
public partial class B : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
   somemethod()
   {
    //reference A.Inner...how?
   }
}
```

The reason for using the innerclass is that I'm bound to a framework, and can't add other things then the two .aspx controls.

Comment: Both classes are in the same namespaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a hickup in VS intellisense. Costed me quite some time, sight. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To create the inner class, just do:

```
var inner = new A.Inner();
```

If `A` is in a different namespace, then

```
var inner = new OtherNamespace.A.Inner();
```